# 301 Redirecting Multiple files to a single subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a site which had multiple pages existing that talked about the same topic and basically had a lot of duplicated content.

I need to redirect all these pages to a single sub directory. The Code I am using right now is -

```
redirect 301 /simple.html http://domain.com/acts
redirect 301 /tough.html http://domain.com/acts
redirect 301 /hard/hardacts.html http://domain.com/acts
```

I'd like to use a cleaner format as otherwise it would lead to a really long `.htaccess` file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create one redirect match rule for each topic like

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+/)*(simple|tough|hardacts)\.html$ http://domain.com/acts
```

This would redirect all `simple`, `tough` and `hardacts` html files found anywhere to `/acts`.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you once again.